# Куда делась буква Т в слове "бесталанный"?

Tags: словообразование

О бездарном, лишенном таланта человеке говорят, что он бесталанный. А куда из этого слова делась буква Т? Почему не "бесталанТный"?

Comment: http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/5411/%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9

Comment: Действительно, зачем по новой эту воду в ступе толочь?
Тем более, что содержательности от таких обсуждений - ноль целых и фиг десятых.
На всяк случай, коротка ссылка:
http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/5411/

Comment: Вопрос давно всем умным людям ясен : **талан** - адаптированная народная форма книжного слова **талант**. Об чем тут говорить!

Answer (score 5):

Слово **бесталанный**, т. е. человек, у которого нет судьбы\доли, образовано от слова **талан** - счастливая доля, судьба[тюрк. талан]. Устар. и нар.-поэт.: Найти свой т.(успех, удачу). Сегодня нам будет т.! Чтоб никогда тебе талану не было!

А слова *бесталанТный*, (во всяком случае, у Лопатина не зафиксировано) не существует. Если у человека нет таланта, т. е. нет выдающейся врождённой способности, особой природной одарённости, то говорят **неталантливый**, и с приставкой бес- это слово не употребляется. Поэтому в слове *бесталанный* и не может быть буквы *т*.